# Unable to get javascript to make first letter of every word LARGER on my site to load properly

Tags: theming, javascript

I'm *trying* to use javascript to make the **first letter of every word** LARGER in titles with the class 'field-name-title' (so basically all nodes).

I found a couple of Javascript-based solutions online, notably [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/82Ebt/4/) and [here](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/css-target-the-first-letter-of-every-word/8108/3). But whenever I try and implement them nothing happens (by which I mean the titles that are supposed to be changed are NOT).

What's I've tried:

1) I replaced the boilerplate class name in the javascript linked to above with my class name (ir. replaced 'title-case' in the one with 'field-name-title', etc.).

2) I've ensured I have a first-letter class in my stylesheet with the following property:

```
.first-letter {
  font-size: 1.4em; // I also tried % such as 115%
}
```

3) I put my javascript file in js/first-letter.js. I referenced it in my .info file as 'scripts[] = js/first-letter.js.

4) I've flushed caches repeatedly (and besides aggregation is turned off).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Alireza's answer doesn't work, try this one.

**js/first-letter.js**

```
(function ($) {
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.field-name-title').html(function(i,el) {
    return el.replace(/\b([A-Z])/g, "<span class=\"first-letter\">$1</span>");
     });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: thanks yet again. that worked perfectly. I can't tell you how much I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the first reference , then change script to this :

```
(function ($) {
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.field-name-title').html(function(i,el) {
      return el.replace(/\b([A-Z])/g, "<span class=\"first-letter\">$1</span>");
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

for more info check [Working with JavaScript and jQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/171213)